# Ibus on Xubuntu 12.04 how to adjust input method specific settings?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, ibus, input-method, chinese

I am on **Xubuntu 12.04** trying to get my PinYin input method in **iBus** to write traditional character. I know that there are suppose to be more preferences under each input methods but I am unable to access them.

For Example, when I select Chewing in the iBus Preferences menu, I cannot select the Preferences button in the Input Method tab to it to adjust settings specific to Chewing. It is the same for the other input methods.

Another thing is that there is no "Lauguage Bar", this is important to me as it would allow me to adjust some of the settings on the fly.

Hope I am clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get a "Language Bar" by selecting "IBus"　icon, then "Preferences", then "Show Language　Panel"　->　"Always"

Comment: I had forgotten to mark this as correct. Thank you!